# Keyboard input in Qt

Tags: linux, qt, embedded

I am working on a Qt application running on embedded Linux. I am pretty new to this Qt business since I have just started it a month back, so understand that I'm not that *object-oriented* ... :P

I have the Qt applications running on my target running Linux. The Qt documentation  http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qt-embedded-pointer.html says that we have to enable touchscreen, USB keyboard, keypad, etc. by exporting certain variables. Namely,

```
export QWS_MOUSE_PROTO=tslib:/dev/input/event1
export QWS_KEYBOARD="linuxinput:/dev/input/event0 usb:/dev/input/event2"
```

well, as you can guess, first line sets the mouse device in QT as touchscreen. "tslib" is the touchscreen library, and the "event1" is the node representing the touchscreen. Similarly, second line is for on-board keypad (event0), and USB keyboard (event2).

Now, the touchscreen work very well. But the problem is with either keyboard. If I do not export the second variable, namely **QWS_KEYBOARD** , then the application runs fine. But if I do export the second variable, the application goes into stopped state (SIGSTOP) as soon as it is launched. This is evident from ps output. I can not make it work with SIGCONT.

I am going to try and reconfigure Qt from source. Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: Have you tried using QWS_KEYBOARD with only one device listed (i.e. `export QWS_KEYBOARD="linuxinput:/dev/intput/event0"`)?

Comment: Yes I have, with the same result. I cant understand why is it going into stopped state. Obviously it has to do with this QWS_KEYBOARD , ...just cant figure out what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can not believe this but setting the QWS_KEYBOARD variable as null solved the problem.
Found it in the Qt developer FAQ http://developer.qt.nokia.com/faq/answer/why_doesnt_my_keyboard_work_after_i_have_done_an_export_qws_keyboard_dev_tt

```
export QWS_KEYBOARD=""
```

Well, it did not completely solve the problem since I still have to include the native keypad along with the USB keyboard.

Anyway, I am able to move to fields using the arrow/TAB keys. Text input works well. Although CAPS-LOCK and NUM-LOCK do not seem to work. SHIFT works. I am able to terminate the application by Ctrl+Alt+Bkspce. So, for the time being, I am able to input text at least.

Will post if any improvements.

Comment: Sadly, the requirement got cancelled, so work was never carried forward on this topic :(

Comment: FYI, though not yet solved - I believe I found my problem: https://bugreports.qt.io/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/QTBUG-9843