# Qt embedded linux event watcher

Tags: c++, linux, qt, events, keyboard

I am facing a big problem regarding keyboard input reading in my Qt embedded application ( [Cannot use keyboard within Qt app without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31161989/cannot-use-keyboard-within-qt-app-without-sudo?noredirect=1#comment50355805_31161989) ). This problem is going for a very long time I dont think it is going to finally be resolved in the normal way. Since my Qt app doesnt see the keyboard events (which is `/dev/input/event1`) I think I am forced to watch the device file mysalfe and wait for events to happen and interpret them by hand.

In a raw c++ application I would go for something like this:

```
/** BB-BONE-GPIO Test code to test the GPIO-KEYS interface.
* Written by Derek Molloy (www.derekmolloy.ie) for the book
* Exploring BeagleBone.
*
* This code is based on work in the document:
*    www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input.txt
*
* Written by Derek Molloy for the book "Exploring BeagleBone: Tools and 
* Techniques for Building with Embedded Linux" by John Wiley & Sons, 2014
* ISBN 9781118935125. Please see the file README.md in the repository root 
* directory for copyright and GNU GPLv3 license information.            */


#include<iostream>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<linux/input.h>
using namespace std;

#define KEY_PRESS 1
#define KEY_RELEASE 0

int main(){
   int fd, count=0;
   struct input_event event[64];
   if(getuid()!=0){
      cout << "You must run this program as root. Exiting." << endl;
      return -1;
   }
   cout << "Starting BB-BONE-GPIO Test (press 10 times to end):" << endl;
   if ((fd = open("/dev/input/event1", O_RDONLY)) < 0){
      perror("Failed to open event1 input device. Exiting.");
      return -1;
   }
   while(count < 20){  // Press and Release are one loop each
      int numbytes = (int)read(fd, event, sizeof(event));
      if (numbytes < (int)sizeof(struct input_event)){
         perror("The input read was invalid. Exiting.");
         return -1;
      }
      for (int i=0; i < numbytes/sizeof(struct input_event); i++){
         int type = event[i].type;
         int val  = event[i].value;
         int code = event[i].code;
         if (type == EV_KEY) {
            if (val == KEY_PRESS){
               cout << "Press  : Code "<< code <<" Value "<< val<< endl;
            }
            if (val == KEY_RELEASE){
               cout << "Release: Code "<< code <<" Value "<< val<< endl;
            }
         }
      }
      count++;
   }
   close(fd);
   return 0;
}
```

I was wondering either Qt library has any higher level mechanisms allowing me to do such thing? I was looking for some but I have only found `QKeyPress` class. Or do I need to do it the bare C way? I would apreciate all help!

Edit:
I have just implemented the above code in the `main` of my Qt app, before the `MainWindow` object is created. The code works, which means the application has all the needed rights to read the input. Why doesnt Qt interpret it then?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `QKeyEvent` class to get keyboard events. You can catch keyboard event as below

```
void yourClass :: keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if (event->key() == Qt::Key_P)
        qDebug() << "Key P is Pressed";
}
```

If you are not getting keyboard events at all then you check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471951/keyboard-input-in-qt)

Comment: I have seen this link and every other link on the internet regarding this i think... Literally... It doesnt work in my case, thats why I want to watch the device manually. My app doesnt stop with sigfault, it just doesnt see the key presses.

Comment: in your beaglebone terminal type `sudo nano /etc/environment` then add `QWS_KEYBOARD` lines and reboot

Comment: Also, something that makes me wonder- When I run the app directly with sudo and the keyboard works, the attached usb keyboard works as well (one keyboard is usb and another one is `event1`), no matter what QWS_KEYBOARD is.

Comment: why dont you run your code as `sudo` always ? any specific reason ?

Comment: I wish that worked. When I run with sudo via ssh- it doesnt work. If i run a startup script in `rc.local` with sudo- it doesnt work as well, and thats the most important case, app should start at system boot. This is driving me nuts. It only works if i run it with sudo after i manually log in and run in on the attached keyboard and lcd screen. And btw, I am root in every case.

Comment: So, do you know maybe a way using Qt libs to watch the file in an efficient way?

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło : I tried on Beagle Bone directly. Type `sudo nano /etc/environment` then add `QWS_KEYBOARD=""`, then keyboard works, using `Ctrl+C`, closes the App

Comment: But does it work when you type that via ssh and through startup script in rc.local? Thats the problem. Also can u type in anytging or only kill the program with ctrl c?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82255/discussion-between-amol-and-lukasz-przenioslo).